# Django is this chaining tasks?

Tags: django, celery

I have a celery task that adds messages to a database like so:

```
class ProcessRequests(Task):

    def run(self, batch):

        for e in q:
            msg = Message.objects.create(
                recipient_number=e.mobile,
                content=batch.content,
                sender=e.contact_owner,
                billee=batch.user,
                sender_name=batch.sender_name
            )
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=2)
            msg.send(gateway)
```

Then in the  **msg.send(gateway)** model there is another task which actually sends the message and runs this:

```
class SendMessage(Task):
    name = "Sending SMS"
    max_retries = 10
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_id, gateway_id=None, **kwargs):
        logging.debug("About to send a message.")


        so some stuff here

        logging.debug("Done sending message.")
```

This all works fine (with over 1000 messages tested), but I read somewhere that you should not chain tasks together, however **this is not chaining, right**? I don't wait for one to finish before the other can run.

Is this example ok in terms of performance etc?

send is something like this:

```
def send(self, message):
    """
    Use this gateway to send a message.

    If ``djcelery`` is installed, then we assume they have set up the
    ``celeryd`` server, and we queue for delivery. Otherwise, we will
    send in-process.

    .. note::
        It is strongly recommended to run this out of process,
        especially if you are sending as part of an HttpRequest, as this
        could take ~5 seconds per message that is to be sent.
    """
    if 'djcelery' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        import sms.tasks
        sms.tasks.SendMessage.delay(message.pk, self.pk)
    else:
        self._send(message)
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `msg.send(gateway)`?

Comment: @NicolasCortot updated with example. thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using django + db + celery to create your own message queue? I suggest you just use a message queue directly, or use celery's queueing features.

Comment: @Marcin could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @Spike I think it's pretty self explanatory. What part of it confused you?

Comment: @ Marcin I read it again and it does make sense, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version, yes you're doing the right thing here.

**Long version:**

The thing is that you don't want something like this:

```
@task
def something(**kwargs):
    # do something here
    something_else.delay().get()

@task
def something_else(**kwargs):
    # do something else here
    pass
```

Which will make `something` wait for the result from `something_else`.

You could even consider moving the creating of the message to a task (so your loop only spawns tasks and doesn't connect to the database straight away).

PS: if you want to keep track of all the results from the result of the `ProcessRequests` task you could execute these as subresults: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html?highlight=asyncresult#subtasks

It can help you group the results: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html?highlight=asyncresult#group-results